# How to escape special characters in string while performing inner join in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, inner-join, special-characters

There is a temp table with words and id's. I have to inner join those words with the main table to get their id's. But the temp table might have special characters along with the words like digits. / .digits / ,digits / digits, / -digits / digits-. In this case, the inner join would not return the value digits. How to escape these characters to make sure the value "digits" is returned?

I need to retain the special characters in the tmp table. Just need to escape those while joining.

```
for t in (select id,word from tmp)
LOOP
      update tmp a
      set a.word_id = (
      select b.id
      from main_table b
      where lower(a.word) = lower(b.word)
      and rownum =1
     )
      where a.word in (select word from tmp where word = t.word);
END LOOP;
```

```
Here is the test data:

CREATE TABLE TMP
   (ID NUMBER,
    WORD VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    WORD_ID NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE main_table
   (ID NUMBER,
    WORD VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE));

insert into tmp(id,word) values ( 1, 'digits' );
insert into tmp(id,word) values ( 2, 'digits.' );
insert into tmp(id,word) values ( 3, '.digits-' );

insert into main_table values( 111, 'digits');
```

The expected outcome is to have word_id'd updated to tmp table from main_table.

```
ID    WORD      WORD_ID
1     digits     111
2     digits.    111
3     .digits-   111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove any non alphanumeric characters before doing the comparison:

```
UPDATE tmp a
SET a.word_id = (SELECT b.id
                 FROM main_table b
                 WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(a.word, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', '') = b.word);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. This worked. The table is updated with it's word ID now. I am now trying to replace substring "digit" in "digits." like www.xxx.com/digits/123<u>digits<u>.
I am expecting "." to be not part of this replace. I am looking for your help to escape special characters while replacing.

Comment: Great.  Open a new question and I'm sure someone will be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

[**TRANSLATE**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690) is your friend here.

Simple define the charaters that sould be preserved - they are defined identical in both `TRANSLATE`strings and charaters that should be removed, they are mapped to NULL.

An example of such transaformation is presented in this query

```
select word,
translate(lower(word),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.-#*+',
                      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') word_clean
from tmp;

WORD       WORD_CLEAN
---------- ----------
digits     digits    
digits.    digits    
.digits-   digits
```

The join will look something like this

```
select tmp.word tmp_word,  main_table.word main_word
from tmp
left outer join  main_table
on translate(lower(tmp.word),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.-#*+',
                          'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = main_table.word
```

Note that I'm using `lower` to eliminate upper case - adjust if required.

Note also, that the `TRANSLATE` option will yield far better performance that the option with `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `[^[:alnum:]]` `POSIX` pattern within `regexp_replace()` function in the `WHERE` condition of the subselect within the `UPDATE` statement :

> `regexp_replace(t.word,'[^[:alnum:]]') = m.word`

where `t` is alias for the table `tmp`, `m` is for `main_table`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another way to do it.

```
 update tmp a
      set a.word_id = (
      select b.id
      from main_table b
      where lower(a.word) like concat(concat('%',b.word),'%') 
      and rownum =1
```